# Existence of one parameter subgroups in homotopie classes of Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\alpha: [0,1] \to G$ a smooth path, connecting the neutral element $n_G$ of the group with a group element $g$, i.e. $\alpha(0)=n_G$ and $\alpha(1)=g$.

Can we find a homotopic one-parameter subgroup $\gamma: {\Bbb R} \to G$ connecting the neutral element of the group with the group element $g$, i.e. $\gamma(0) = n_G$ and $\gamma(1) = g$, and $\gamma$ restricted to $[0,1]$ is in the same homotopy class as $\alpha$?

If I have a homotopy class for connecting a group element to the neutral element, can I chose a representative path in this homotopy class to be a one parameter group?

Comment: If $G$ is non-compact, then, in general, the group exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ is not surjective.  In particular, there may not be any one-parameter subgroup containing $g$.

Comment: Thanx for pointing this out. That's why I assume there is already a connecting path. I want to know if I can transform this into a one-parameter group without losing homotopie type.

Comment: I don't understand how the assumption helps.  In, for example, $G = Sl(n,\mathbb{R})$, every $g\in G$ can be connected to the identity by some path, but many $g$ cannot be connected by any one-parameter subgroup at all.

Comment: Hm. Cool comment. I also don't understand it any more. I was particularly interested in $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ and Lorentz group. I now realize that my intuition wrt $SL(2)$ and Lorentz group somehow needs some brushing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $G$ is compact with a **bi**-invariant Riemannian metric; then one-parameter subgroups are exactly geodesics containing the origin [e.g. do Carmo, *Riemmanian Geometry*, Chapter 3, Exercise 3b]. Then the existence of a geodesic within a path homotopy class follows by finding a path of minimal Lipschitz constant within the homotopy class of $\alpha$.

Comment: That's a very nice approach and it looks like it works in the compact case. Any idea what I can do in the non-compact case? For example in the case of the Lorentz group?

Comment: The restricted Lorentz group is isomorphic to $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$, which does not have an onto exponential map [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Non-surjectiveness_of_exponential_mapping_for_SL(2,_C)).